# crystal reports count instance by group then sum

Tags: count, crystal-reports, cumulative-sum, summarize

My subreport has groupings on Account ID then Invoice No.  Within the Account ID I could have several Invoice No's.

For example:

> Account 1234

- Invoice 6789
- Invoice 5432
- Invoice 5432
- Invoice 9999

What I want is count of invoices.  Using the example I should get a count of 3.  There are 3 unique invoice numbers under the account id.  I have tried a running total, formulas and summary.

Comment: what is your problem and where are you struck?

Comment: Make a summary of invoice distinct sum

Comment: The subreport treats each invoice as a group.  If I use count then, using my example, I get 1, 2, and 1.  If I use distinct then I get 1, 1, and 1.  The distinct is accurate, but I then want to count or sum those results and see 3.  Putting the count in the report footer doesn't work either.  Seems to count the invoice for each group.

Comment: Making a summary and putting the field in the footer returns 1, 1, and 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Distinct Keyword in sql query or linq You Can Solve This Problem.**

```
var data = (from n in tbldemo select n).Distinct();

Now Set data to your crystal report data source. It will helps you.
```

Comment: Is this done using the SQL Expression?  If so I have not used that feature.  What are "n" and "tbldemo"?  Are they the column and table I want to use in my count?  Is there any special syntax?

Comment: n which holds an individual reference for each object of the tbldemo.Yes tbldemo is table.